# Can ridges on the bottom of shakers be used to help with dispensing?

Tags: physics

From https://twitter.com/LipBitinANNAmal/status/1078840770864529408 156,700 Retweets 376,681 Likes (probably not the original author):

> How old were y’all when you found out the ridges on the bottom of the salt/pepper shakers had a purpose?
>
> [Video of a shaker not dispensing much, until two shakers were rubbed against each other]

Can the ridges on the bottom of shakers be used to help with dispensing?

Comment: What sort of evidence would you like to see here?

Comment: Can they? Well the video seems pretty convincing. Are ridges put there intentionally for this purpose or is it a happy coincidence? Now that's an interesting question.

Comment: Yeah, shakers have a bottom so you can bang the bottom on the table when you need to loosen things up.

Comment: You can use vibrations to get a powder out of a dispenser and most salt and pepper shakers don’t have those ridges so many of this type of meme are wrong. In fact there are plenty of other devices used in cooking that use vibrations to dispense something such as flour.

Comment: @Oddthinking that the ridges are necessary, and sufficient, for this facilitated dispensing functionality. For example, is the video staged (ridges are not sufficient), or would two containers that didn't have ridges behave similarly (ridges are not necessary)?

Comment: If nothing else, from a culinary perspective, the amount of pepper dispensed using the ridges is as we say in the industry, "way too f$#&ing much"

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'd expect shakers have a bottom so the contents don't fall out ;-)

Comment: @Kevin - No, that's why they have the tops.  They tend to be defective, though.